# Number of Integer solutions to $x+y+z+w=11$ subject to the constraints $4 \geq x,y,z,w \geq 0$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$$x+y+z+w=11$$
First of all using the stars and bars method for all solutions subject to constraints $x,y,z,w\geq0$
I get
$$\frac{14!}{3!11!}=364$$
Now considering choosing one of the variables and letting it be greater than 4 so we can eliminate those solutions.
$x\geq5$
$x-5\geq0$
$x-5=a$
$a\geq0$
$$a+y+z+w=6$$
for which number of solutions will be
$$\frac{9!}{3!6!}$$
Then we have to choose one of the variables too so therefore.
$$4*\frac{9!}{3!6!}=336$$

Now considering two variables can be greater than 5, using similar approach it comes out to be:
$$\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{4!}{3!1!}=24$$
So according to me the final answer should be
$$364-336-24=4$$ which is incorrect, and the correct answer given is
$$364-336+24=52$$
I am not aware why we are adding the last case instead of subtracting it, maybe I am missing some crucial insight on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should study [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) carefully, while applying inclusion-exclusion, you will find that the +/- signs always alternate to correct for multiple counting, and you can get the answer more simply as

$$\binom{14}3 -\binom41\binom93 + \binom42\binom43 = 52$$

representing total ways without any upper limit and applying inclusion-exclusion to correct for $1,2$ cells violating the upper limit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But isn't the last case where two variables are greater than 4, so shouldn't we be subtracting it, I am trying to think about it intuitively as I have not studied this principle in detail.

Comment: @BlackEmperor You already subtracted that case when you subtracted 336. But you subtracted it _twice_. You are adding back in to account for having subtracted it twice.

Comment: @2'59'2 But in that second case I only took 1 variable as greater than 4 at a time, so why will that include the latter case where two variables are greater than 4 at a time. I am not able to understand this point. Maybe could you explain it using set theory as I am well versed in that.

Comment: When we have subtracted $\binom41\binom93$, for single cells exceeding the limit, *we do not make any assumption for other cells,* so in the figure, more than one cell  exceeding are already included and thus have to be subtracted in the next step.

Comment: @BlackEmperor For example $(x,y,z,w)=(4,4,2,1)$ is counted once when you are counting the options with $x=4$. And again when you are counting the options with $y=4$.

Comment: @2'59'2 So in the second case,
$x\geq5$ also contains cases of $y\geq5$, $z\geq5$, $w\geq5$.
Similarly,
$y\geq5$ also contains cases of $x\geq5$, $z\geq5$, $w\geq5$.
So we are subtracting the cases where two variables are greater than or equal to 5, twice. Hence we adding the third case.
As a sidenote, is there a better way to do these questions, as I feel this method is prone to missing cases and committing mistakes.

Comment: This way is not so difficult if you streamline the inclusion-exclusion alternating +/- signs. Eg if for the same problem, the sum required had been $16$, the answer would be $\binom{19}3 - \binom41\binom{14}3 +\binom42\binom{9}3-\binom43\binom43 $  However, if you want a different method, you could find the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^4$ (generating function approach) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E11+in+%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%29%5E4

Comment: Of course, for a sum of $16$, you could get the answer of $1$ without any technique, the point is that with $4$ cells, there can at most be four terms in the inclusion-exclusion computation.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative**

Define the followings:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p&=4-x \\
q&=4-y \\
r&=4-z \\
s&=4-w
\end{aligned}
$$

Then we have, with $0\leq p,q,r,s\leq 4$:

$$
p+q+r+s=5
$$

Which is simpler because only one variable can violate the constraint at a time

Comment: Amazing, this makes the problem way more easy.
Thank you for the answer.